# Laravel - Creating an object from a JSON array to save it in a SQL database

Tags: php, sql, arrays, json, laravel

What I am trying to do is to send a JSON array (that was gotten from Guzzle) to my SQL database. I have gotten to the point where I am able to get the response and display the gotten JSON array on a webpage. The array is defined as the `$data` variable. The `$data` variable gets decoded using this:

```
$data = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
```

This is able to get the JSON and decode it with no problem. The part I am stuck on is taking the `$data` variable, processing it and sending it to my database. From what I understand is that you are required to convert the JSON into an array and then send it to the database.

The JSON format is like this:

```
[{
  "INTLDES": "2017-042Z",
  "NORAD_CAT_ID": "42848",
  "OBJECT_TYPE": "TBA",
  "SATNAME": "OBJECT Z",
  "COUNTRY": "TBD",
  "LAUNCH": "2017-07-14",
  "SITE": "TTMTR",
  "DECAY": null,
  "PERIOD": "96.52",
  "INCLINATION": "97.61",
  "APOGEE": "597",
  "PERIGEE": "586",
  "COMMENT": null,
  "COMMENTCODE": null,
  "RCSVALUE": "0",
  "RCS_SIZE": null,
  "FILE": "6242",
  "LAUNCH_YEAR": "2017",
  "LAUNCH_NUM": "42",
  "LAUNCH_PIECE": "Z",
  "CURRENT": "Y",
  "OBJECT_NAME": "OBJECT Z",
  "OBJECT_ID": "2017-042Z",
  "OBJECT_NUMBER": "42848"
}]
```

My Satellite Model goes like this:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'intldes',
    'norad_cat_id',
    'object_type',
    'satname',
    'country',
    'launch',
    'site',
    'decay',
    'period',
    'inclination',
    'apogee',
    'perigee',
    'comment',
    'commentcode',
    'rcsvalue',
    'rcs_size',
    'file',
    'launch_year',
    'launch_num',
    'launch_piece',
    'current',
    'object_name',
    'object_id',
    'object_number'
];
```

My migrations file:

```
Schema::create('satellites', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('intldes');
    $table->string('norad_cat_id');
    $table->string('object_type');
    $table->string('satname');
    $table->string('country');
    $table->string('launch')->nullable();
    $table->string('site')->nullable();
    $table->string('decay')->nullable();
    $table->string('period')->nullable();
    $table->string('inclination')->nullable();
    $table->string('apogee')->nullable();
    $table->string('perigee')->nullable();
    $table->string('comment')->nullable();
    $table->string('commentcode')->nullable();
    $table->string('rcsvalue')->nullable();
    $table->string('rcs_size')->nullable();
    $table->string('file')->nullable();
    $table->string('launch_year')->nullable();
    $table->string('launch_num')->nullable();
    $table->string('launch_piece')->nullable();
    $table->string('current')->nullable();
    $table->string('object_name');
    $table->string('object_id');
    $table->string('object_number');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I tried making an `$object` array, which did not work.

**TL;DR:** I want to take the `$data` variable, which contains the decoded JSON and create something that allows it to get saved into my 'satellites' SQL database.

**EDIT:** Here is the full Satellite controller:

```
    public function displayer(){
    $api = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'https://www.space-track.org',
    'cookies' => true, 
    ]); $api->post('ajaxauth/login', [
      'form_params' => [
         'identity' => '#', 
         'password' => '#', 
     ],
    ]);
    $response = $api->get('basicspacedata/query/class/satcat/orderby/INTLDES%20desc/limit/5/metadata/false');
    $data = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
    $data = array_change_key_case($data, CASE_LOWER);
    $model = Satellite::create($data);
    dd($data);
}
```

Comment: This may not be relevant to the question, but that long array of $fillable can be changed to be `protected $guarded = ['id'];` (instead) blacklisting only `id` while others become mass assignable.

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi Will edit it now!

Comment: You don't have to edit actually, just for anyone who finds it useful, your code is already okay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your JSON key names match up nicely with your model attributes, with the exception of being capitalised.

Try mapping the data keys to lowercase and then creating your model instance.
Per @OmisakinOluwatobi suggestion, you can use pass `true` to `json_decode` to retrieve the data as an array.

**Edit** - I missed that your response data was an array of objects. The following update will iterate over the response data and create a new `Satellite` for each.

```
// Retrieve data from response
$data = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);

// Iterate over response data
foreach ($data as $attributes) {
    // Change attribute keys to lowercase
    $attributes = array_change_key_case($attributes, CASE_LOWER);

    // Create satellite model
    Satellite::create($attributes);
}
```

Comment: how about json_decode($content, true) to return array?

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi - excellent suggestion. I'd forgotten about addressing the object -> array part of the question.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, I think this is the code I need. but I am getting an error - `Call to undefined method App\Http\Controllers\Satellite::create()`.     I think I am forgetting something.

Comment: `use App\Satellite;` thats what is missing @D.777KLM

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi That fixed it but now I get an error that states `must be of the type array, string given`. It seems like to does not convert to a array. I added the `true` as you suggested.

Comment: @D.777KLM what is the whole error message? Including stacktrace - update your question. Can you post the full code for your `Satellite` model?

Comment: dd the result in the data, i.e dd($data) and see if you have what you need

Comment: The error I get is: `Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\space-observe.dev\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 681` Here is a screenshot of the array: http://i.imgur.com/UUiQ7A5.png with `dd($data)` @OmisakinOluwatobi

Comment: Ahhh. I didn't see that you were getting an array of objects back in your JSON. See my updated answer.

Comment: @fubar may not be necessary, but what about mass insert? hmm okay the need to change the case... an issue..

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi - that's an option. My only thought is that you'd need to iterate over the data to change the keys, and then `insert` iterates over the data again, so you'd be going through it twice either way. Also `insert` doesn't run any model event listeners to my knowledge.

Comment: I think you are right, at least I know that for mass update (created and updated events are not fired)

Answer (score 0):

It is actually as simple as `$encoded = json_encode($request->your_array);`. This `$encoded` will now be "savable" to sql database. When you later access the encoded data, you can use a JSON parser to convert back to a json array. Example using jQuery `var your_array = $.parseJSON($response.body);`